# Yii2 - Upgrade from basic application to Advanced application

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have developed a Basic application in Yii2. It contains 3 models and respective controllers and views, no extension, no theme.

I now think that I should make that application with advanced template for future extend-ability.

Can I convert the basic app directly to advanced app or make a new one?

If I can convert the basic app, what are the steps?

I searched on google but can't find anything related to it except the comparison of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You need modify [this bootstrap file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php). It's make avalible use `\common`, `\frontend`, `\backend` and `\console` namespaces in project.

In this way you can create any quantity of applications in your project.